# Recursive Function Missing Return Statement

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

I'm new to recursion and I don't see why this function won't compile. It is apparently missing a return statement. From testing it also seems as though my return statements do not return?

```
// recursive search method
public BinaryTree<T> recursiveSearch(BinaryTree<T> t, T key) {
    if (key.compareTo(t.getData()) < 0) {
        if (t.getLeft() != null) {
            recursiveSearch(t.getLeft(), key);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else if (key.compareTo(t.getData()) > 0) {
        if (t.getRight() != null) {
            recursiveSearch(t.getRight(), key);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } else if (key.compareTo(t.getData()) == 0) { // key is found
        return t;
    } else { // not in binary tree
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to return the call to your function `return recursiveSearch(t.getRight(), key);`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is on the lines inside the `if` branches that make recursive calls.

Your code will behave correctly when it reaches any of your `else` branches, because all of them have `return null`. If code takes one of the `if` branches, however, the control would reach the end of your method without hitting a `return`. The fix is simple - add the missing `return`s:

```
return recursiveSearch(t.getRight(), key);
```

Comment: I agree with what you said, this occurs at 2 places both when use the recursiveSearch function, just place a return value before each.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is missing a return statement for the *recursion* statements.

```
public BinaryTree<T> recursiveSearch(BinaryTree<T> t, T key)
{
    if (key.compareTo(t.getData())<0){
        if (t.getLeft() != null) {
            recursiveSearch(t.getLeft(), key); // This case doesn't return anything
        } else { return null;}
    } else if (key.compareTo(t.getData())>0) {
        if (t.getRight() != null) {
            recursiveSearch(t.getRight(), key); // This case doesn't return anything
        } else {return null;}
    } else if (key.compareTo(t.getData())==0){ // key is found
        return t;
    } else {
        //not in binary tree
        return null;
    }
}
```

I dont know your program logic, but if I have to guess, you might wanna add a return statement to the *recursive* calls. Like so,

```
return recursiveSearch(t.getLeft(), key);
```

and

```
return recursiveSearch(t.getRight(), key);
```